# Significato di "accesparsi"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Giunse sull'ultimo albero dei parchi, un platano. Giù digradava la valle sotto un cielo di corone di nubi e fumo che saliva da qualche tetto d'ardesia, casolari nascosti dietro le ripe come mucchi di sassi; un cielo di foglie alzate in aria dai fichi e dai ciliegi; e più bassi prugni e peschi divaricavano tarchiati rami; tutto si vedeva, anche l'erba, fogliolina a fogliolina, ma non il colore della terra, ricoperta dalle pigre foglie della zucca o dall'**accesparsi** di lattughe o verze nei semenzai; e così era da una parte e dall'altra del V in cui s'apriva la valle ad un imbuto alto di mare.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "accesparsi" in questo brano? Ho cercato "accespare" e "accesparsi" in parecchi dizionari, ma non li ho trovati.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un cespo di insalata è la forma che assumono le foglie di questo vegetale quando nasce dal terreno.

In questo caso l'accesparsi di lattughe o verze vuole dare un senso di movimento alla descrizione del paesaggio, probabilmente per far trasparire un senso di vivo, in quanto ancora sono in fase di crescita dal terreno.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Figurati! Grazie per il benvenuto ;) 
Se la risposta ti sembra completa segnala come accettata

Comment: Ho l'abitudine di aspettare un po' di tempo  prima di accettare una risposta.

Comment: Va benissimo, buona abitudine